# Where did the nasal sound in the Portuguese word "sim" come from?

Tags: phonology, historical-linguistics, romance-languages, portuguese

Among the descendants of the Latin word *sic* ("thus, so, or just like that"), only the Portuguese word *sim* ends with a nasal consonant. Actually, in modern Portuguese, it ends with a nasal vowel, [sĩ], which must have developed from [sim] by assimilation. Compare this with its "sister" words, taken from the [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sic#Latin), which have all dropped the final [k]:

> - Aromanian: shi
> - French: si, ainsi
> - Italian: sì, così
> - Romanian: și
> - Spanish: sí , así
> - Catalan: així

The closest word is the French (no surprise, given we are talking about nasalization) *ainsi*, which comes from Latin (*ad*) + *in* + *sic*.
So where did this nasal at the end in Portuguese *sim* come from? Could it be a further development from French? Something like *ainsi* becoming *assim* (and later, *sim*), by metathesis?

Comment: I don't have evidence, but this does look like a case of progressive nasalization: _in_ + _sic_ -> _sĩ_.

Comment: It's not unusual for common short utterances (such as the words for "yes" and "no") to acquire a final labial element (cf. English "yep" and "nope"). It's a natural byproduct of quickly shutting your mouth after uttering a single syllable. This is speculation, but maybe that's what happened in Portuguese here.

Comment: @voikya that seems a reasonable hypothesis for labial stops, but I'm not so sure it explains the appending of nasal consonants and vowels.

Comment: @voikya: and note that at least in contemporary Portuguese, the '-m' is purely a marker of nasalisation, it has no labial element. I don't know whether or not there was a labial element in this word in the past, but I would guess not.

Comment: This quite unrelated paper cites sic > sim as an example of analogical change, on the model of antonym não: http://sealang.net/sala/archives/pdf8/kosaka2002affiliation.pdf

Comment: @ROBOKiTTY That's surprising! I'll look into it.

Comment: One possibility stems from the fact that non-nasal /i/ and nasal /ĩ/ are fairly similar acoustically, more so than other nasal/non-nasal pairs. (This is because there isn't much space to nasalize /i/ without blocking the mouth completely and producing a syllabic nasal; hence /ĩ/ isn't very strongly nasalized.) Thus it would be easier for L1 learners to confuse them.

Comment: I do not know how it happened, but I would point the similar *nec* -> *nem* derivation. Maybe that doesn't make it a regular change, but it is not an isolated phenomenon either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the late sixteenth century, there was a sporadic sound change in Portuguese which caused some stressed, word-final /i/s to become nasalised.

Examples: *sim*, *marfim*, *assim*, *metim*, *morim*.

An older theory is that it was an influence of the nasalisation present in the antonym *não*.

Comment: It have affected even Tupi loanwords in Brazil, for example the Portuguese "capim", from Tupi "kaapii"; or "tupiniquim" from Tupi "tupiniki".

Answer (score 6):

I think you’re looking at this backwards.

The Portuguese word spelled *sim* did not come to be pronounced `[sĩ]` through some sort of assimilation of nasal consonant, the way occurred with Portuguese *fim* `[fĩ]` and *um* `[ũ]`, or even *sem* < Latin *sine*.

Rather, the word came to be pronounced that way, and so came to spelled in a way that indicated its nasalization, and ‹im› is simply how one spells `[ĩ]` there.

Although not all nasalization in Portuguese is explicitly marked in the orthography (for example, in *muito* `[mũĩ̯tu]`),  with *sim* `[sĩ]`, it is. Similarly, Portuguese *assim* `[ɐˈsĩ]` is written with an ‹im›.  This developed from Latin *ad sic*, “with nasalization”.<sup>[[ref](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=assim)]</sup>  The history of Portuguese is complex and uneven, and did not settle down until much later than in languages such as neighboring Spanish did back in the 1500s.

Nasalization and palatalizations were variously marked with an tilde,  with an *n* or *m*, or with a following *h* — or with some combination of these:<sup>[[ref](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortografia_da_l%EDngua_portuguesa#Hist.C3.B3ria_da_ortografia_da_l.C3.ADngua_portuguesa)]</sup>

- cimco > cinco
- grãde > grande
- tẽpo > tempo
- razõ > razom
- camĩho > caminho

In the earliest preserved texts of what would become Portuguese, you see the letter *h* used innovatively, as in *sabha* for *sabia*, or *mha* for what become modern *minha, meu*. For example, Dom Denis wrote in one of his *Cantigas de Amor*:<sup>[[ref](http://cfp.cm-lisboa.pt/pls/htmldb/f?p=334:6:3977332719096491%3a%3a%3a%3aP6_POE_ID,P6_TEP_ID,P6_ANCORA,P6_AUTOR,P6_POEMA,P6_ID,P6_TIPO:2322,16010,7,Dom%20Dinis,%5BPROEN%C7AES%20SOEN%20MUI%20BEM%20TROBAR%5D,73,autor)]</sup>

> *Proençaes soen mui ben trobar
>
>    e dizen eles que é con amor;
>
>    mais os que troban no tempo da frol
>
>    e non en outro, sei eu ben que non
>
>    an tan gran coita no seu coraçon
>
>    qual m'eu por **mha senhor** vejo levar.*

In contrast, Afonso Xº wrote *mia* for the same word used in the same situation in his *Cantigas de Santa Maria*:<sup>[[ref](http://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Cantigas_de_Santa_Maria/LV)]</sup>

> *Con sennor, assi dizia, | chorando mui feramente:
>
>    «**Mia Sennor**, eu a ti venno | como moller que se sente
>
>    de grand' erro que á feito; | mas, Sennor, venna-ch' a mente
>
>    se che fiz algun serviço, | e guarda-me mia pessõa
>
>    Atant' é Santa Maria | de toda bondade bõa...*

Afonso writes other othographically interesting things, like *non poss' eu perdon gãar* for modern Portuguese *ganhar*<sup>[[ref](http://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Cantigas_de_Santa_Maria/III)]</sup>, or *non disse ssi nen non*<sup>[[ref](http://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Cantigas_de_Santa_Maria/CCLXXXIII)]</sup>. There we see that Latin *sic* has for Afonso become *ssi* without the nasalization marking present in *nen*, the same word which would become modern Spanish *ni*, but there unnasalized.

In other places, Afonso uses *mi* as a prepositional object, which modern Portuguese would spell as *mim* with final ‹im› to indicate nasalization, despite there never having been an historical dental consonant.  Similarly, as words like *mha, mia, mi* came to be pronounced with nasalization, these were also reanalysed the way medieval *ũa* would.  On page 147 of *The Romance Languages* <sup>[Harris&Vincent; OUP 1990]</sup>, in the section on historical Portuguese morphology, they write:

> Both the articles show abnormal phonetic developments. In the indefinite article, derived from the numeral UNUM, the feminine forms would ordinarily have been denasalised, as ∗[ua], ∗[uas], but retain their nasality, by analogy with the masculine. The modern feminine forms developed in the seventeenth sentury, though glide epenthesesis *ũa > ∗uw̃a > uma* **possibly influenced by the orthographic form of the masculine,** *(h)um*.

On page 143, the authors explain that ‹‑m› and ‹‑n› are modern orthographic indicators of nasality, which in earlier days used a tilde, or which were not indicated in the orthography at all. They warn that **“in many cases (e.g. *tã* = *ta(n)*?) its interpretation is a matter of dispute between linguists and paleographers.”**

So analogous forms of writing nasalized vowels using a following ‹m› in the orthography influenced how nasal vowels would coming to be written as orthography became more regular.  There was no historical nasal consonant left in *mea > mha, mia > minha*, but it got written that way, and this in turn came to influence the pronunciation.  Similarly, the spellings of *mim, sim, assim* represent the comparatively recent orthographic invention/convention for writing a `[ĩ]` there, despite there never having been a nasal consonant present to assimilate. In some cases, there was; in some cases there was not; and in some cases, it is a matter of some dispute just what was actually going on there.

Comment: Your answer is incredibly detailed and interesting! +1 for that. Nevertheless, it doesn't explain how (or why) [si] nasalized in the first place.

Comment: @OtavioMacedo I’m still working on that part. I’m convinced there something interesting with 
    *sic > ssi > sim; 
    ad sic > assim;
    mihi > mi > mim;
    mea > mha, mia. mi > minha.* Those that start with *m* might possibly be explained by anticipatory assimilation, but those that start from *sic* cannot be.

Comment: Actually, the _Cantigas de Santa Maria_ by Afonso X are written in Old Galician (or in the Galician variant of Galician-Portuguese).

Comment: The Galician-Portuguese "mia" into Modern-Portuguese "minha" is by nasal assimilation that affected some initial syllables starting with m followed by a vowel sequence (either the hiatus "ia", or a falling diphthong not followed by another vowel). Compare to mai>mãe, muito>muito (actually `/mũj.to/`, the nasal assimilation isn't indicated in spelling), but meia>meia and maior>maior (both not nasalized).

Comment: @Seninha That's very interesting, and sounds completely plausible.

Comment: Correction on my previous comment: *"[...] (either the hiatus 'ia', or a falling diphthong **in '-i'** not followed by another vowel) [...]*." Only the vowel sequences containing /i/ "ia, ai, ui..." got this change. It differs from si/assi > sim/assim, which have the similar final "-i" context, because it was applied in cases where the "i" may or may not be final (e.g., "muito", "minha"). Without the correction, I was mistakenly saying that the -u diphthongs "meu" and "mau" evolved into "mẽo" and "mão".